# How to position div with sticky?

Tags: html, css

I need to fixed position with scrolling so I used `position:sticky` but I not positioning where I placed. I tried with this.[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/harshana2007/QrJ66/)

Comment: don't use <Center> tag it is deprecated..!!

Comment: Ok i delete that tag. But still not working..

Comment: change top:500; to bottom:0 and position:sticky to , Position:fixed

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QrJ66/14/ check this fiddle

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian .. sir it not  working. i need to position fixed with scrolling

Comment: fixed with scrolling?? why do you need footer to be fixed and scrolling?? wait give me a minute ill give you the exact code

Comment: do you need this?? http://jsfiddle.net/QrJ66/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

---

```
<div id="footer" >
        <p><a href="#">copywrite @PP 2014</a></p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

---

```
#footer {
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color: purple;
    z-index:60;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
#footer p a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-text-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-text-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    -o-text-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    -ms-text-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

**Fiddle**

---

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QrJ66/14/)

**Output:**

---

[image]

**Suggestions:**

---

Don't Use `<center>` tag, it is deprecated.

> This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may
>   still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it
>   in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any
>   time.

**[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center)**

---

Changed made to your **CSS** is

```
#footer {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `fixed` instead of `sticky`.

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
```

Comment: I used fixed.But it's not scrolling.

Comment: If you want the footer positioned at the bottom replace `top:500px` with `bottom:0px`. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

`position: sticky` is not very well supported by most of the browsers at the moment.
Refer this link: http://caniuse.com/css-sticky

You might want to use `position: fixed` till then.

Comment: But fixed will not scrolling .. :(

Comment: Could you provide an example for what you need to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

set css

```
#footer{
   display:block;
   position:fixed:
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
position:absolute;
```

If you are trying to position the div fixed with first fixed element in the document.

or else you have to use

```
position:fixed;
```

If you want div to be fixed even when u scroll window also, this is fixed with your browser, this can be used while desining pop-up's.
check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)